# How to texturepaint my auto eyes addon?

Tags: texturing, add-on

https://pasteall.org/blend/b4c4dfe1669b473a8489b02daf3c2099

I've tried to look at many tutorials but all I know is that it isn't possible to painting texture.

I just need to draw illustration on the back on my eyes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That shader is very complicated but it looks like it doesn't use any textures at all.  It's all procedurally generated.  I don't think you can paint if there are no texture maps to store the painted data.

Comment: @DaleCieslak Does that mean I can draw by adding a texture map? Is there any way?

Comment: Yes you can, you need texture image as some sort of input and add it to your procedural material with MixRGB node for example...

Comment: @MikoCG Thanks miko. I try to fix it to use mixRgb but I didn't work. How can I do that?

Comment: That's not what I meant, you cannot add shader output into mixRGB, you can add it into mixShader but then you need to place that texture into some shader node, this is a bit complicated to just write it